# ¿Cómo puedo enviar una variable $_SESSION a AJAX?

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, ajax

estoy desarrollando una app marketplace donde usuarios se registran y realizan publicaciones. Actualmente implementé un **datatable** en el panel del usuario para que pueda ver las publicaciones realizadas. El problema surge cuando quiero pasarle a **AJAX** la variable **$_SESSION["id"]** para que este busque en **mysql** y devuelva un **json** con los datos para la **datatable**.

Este es el fragmento que tengo en js donde invoco a **tablaProductos.ajax.php** donde éste devuelve el **json**

```
$('.tablaProductos').DataTable({

    "ajax":"ajax/tablaProductos.ajax.php",
    "deferRender": true,
    "retrieve": true,
    "processing": true,
    "language": {

            "sProcessing":     "Procesando...",
            "sLengthMenu":     "Mostrar _MENU_ registros",
            "sZeroRecords":    "No se encontraron resultados",
            "sEmptyTable":     "Ningún dato disponible en esta tabla",
            "sInfo":           "Mostrando registros del _START_ al _END_ de un total de _TOTAL_",
            "sInfoEmpty":      "Mostrando registros del 0 al 0 de un total de 0",
            "sInfoFiltered":   "(filtrado de un total de _MAX_ registros)",
            "sInfoPostFix":    "",
            "sSearch":         "Buscar:",
            "sUrl":            "",
            "sInfoThousands":  ",",
            "sLoadingRecords": "Cargando...",
            "oPaginate": {
            "sFirst":    "Primero",
            "sLast":     "Último",
            "sNext":     "Siguiente",
            "sPrevious": "Anterior"
            },
            "oAria": {
                "sSortAscending":  ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera ascendente",
                "sSortDescending": ": Activar para ordenar la columna de manera descendente"
            }

    }

});
```

Aqui **tablaProductos.ajax.php**

```
<?php

require_once "../controladores/productos.controlador.php";
require_once "../modelos/productos.modelo.php";




class TablaProductos{

    

  /*=============================================
  MOSTRAR LA TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
  =============================================*/ 

  public function mostrarTablaProductos(){  



    $item = null; /*AQUI TENDRÍA QUE ENVIAR LA VARIABLE $_SESSION["id"] */
    
    $valor = null;

    
    $productos = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarProductos2($item, $valor);


    

    $datosJson = '

        {   
            "data":[';

        for($i = 0; $i < count($productos); $i++){

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS CATEGORÍAS
            =============================================*/

            $item = "id";
            $valor = $productos[$i]["id_categoria"];

            $categorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarCategorias($item, $valor);

            if($categorias["categoria"] == ""){

                $categoria = "SIN CATEGORÍA";
            
            }else{

                $categoria = $categorias["categoria"];
            }

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS SUBCATEGORÍAS
            =============================================*/

            $item2 = "id";
            $valor2 = $productos[$i]["id_subcategoria"];

            $subcategorias = ControladorProductos::ctrMostrarSubCategorias($item2, $valor2);

            if($subcategorias[0]["subcategoria"] == ""){

                $subcategoria = "SIN SUBCATEGORÍA";
            
            }else{

                $subcategoria = $subcategorias[0]["subcategoria"];
            }

            /*=============================================
            AGREGAR ETIQUETAS DE ESTADO
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["estado"] == 0){

                $colorEstado = "btn-danger";
                $textoEstado = "Desactivado";
                $estadoProducto = 1;

            }else{

                $colorEstado = "btn-success";
                $textoEstado = "Activado";
                $estadoProducto = 0;

            }

            $estado = "<button class='btn btn-xs btnActivar ".$colorEstado."' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' estadoProducto='".$estadoProducto."'>".$textoEstado."</button>";


            

            /*=============================================
            TRAER PRECIO
            =============================================*/

            if($productos[$i]["precio"] == 0){

                $precio = "Gratis";
            
            }else{

                $precio = "$ ".number_format($productos[$i]["precio"],2);

            }

            

            
            

            /*=============================================
            TRAER LAS ACCIONES
            =============================================*/

            $acciones = "<div class='btn-group'><button class='btn btn-warning btnEditarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."' data-toggle='modal' data-target='#modalEditarProducto'><i class='fa fa-pencil'></i></button><button class='btn btn-danger btnEliminarProducto' idProducto='".$productos[$i]["id"]."'><i class='fa fa-times'></i></button></div>";

            /*=============================================
            CONSTRUIR LOS DATOS JSON
            =============================================*/


            $datosJson .='[
                    
                    "'.($i+1).'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["titulo"].'",
                    "'.$categoria.'",
                    "'.$subcategoria.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["ruta"].'",
                    "'.$estado.'",
                    "'.$productos[$i]["tipo"].'",
                    "'.$precio.'",          
                    "'.$acciones.'"    

            ],';

        }

        $datosJson = substr($datosJson, 0, -1);

        $datosJson .= ']

        }';
        


        echo $datosJson;

  }


}

/*=============================================
ACTIVAR TABLA DE PRODUCTOS
=============================================*/ 
$activarProductos = new TablaProductos();
$activarProductos -> mostrarTablaProductos();
```

**ctrMostrarProductos2()**

```
static public function ctrMostrarProductos2($item1, $valor1){

        $tabla = "productos";

        $respuesta = ModeloProductos::mdlMostrarProductos2($tabla, $item1, $valor1);

        return $respuesta;
    
    }
```

**mdlMostrarProductos2()**

```
static public function mdlMostrarProductos2($tabla, $item, $valor){

        if($item != null){

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla WHERE id_usuario = $item");

            $stmt -> bindParam(":".$item, $valor, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }else{

            $stmt = Conexion::conectar()->prepare("SELECT * FROM $tabla ORDER BY id DESC");

            $stmt -> execute();

            return $stmt -> fetchAll();

        }

        $stmt -> close();

        $stmt = null;


    }
```

Así tal cual está me devuelve un json con todas las publicaciones de la tabla, pero necesito que solo me traiga las que coincida con el dato ID que debería pasarle pero no se como...

Comment: No estoy 100% seguro, pero creo que en **tablaProductos.ajax.php** puedes capturar el valor de la variable de sesión así: `$item = $_SESSION["id"];`. Intenta y si no te funciona, debes enviar el valor desde la vista en un `input` oculto.

Comment: @DjCrazy No, eso ya lo intenté pero no funciona. Puedo enviar desde la vista un input oculto con el dato, también puedo capturarlo en js, pero no tengo forma de enviarlo a **tablaProductos.ajax.php** o por lo menos no he podido

Comment: @DjCrazy Ya pude, era como dijiste tal cual, pero tenía que añadir en mi archivo tablaProductos.ajax.php la linea `session_start();` sino no me tomaba la asignacion **$item = $_SESSION["id"];**